# MySQL user-defined @variable is empty in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I got problem with following query. When Im running it in mysql workbench, the user defined variable @cid is being filled correctly, however when i run it in PHP the variable is empty. Im using mysqli_query mechanism.

Its complicated query but as I have already said - works fine in mysql WB but not in PHP. In PHP count is being returned correctly so looks like whole query works except of storing of value in @cid variable.

Query:

```
SELECT count(*),@cid FROM users WHERE yfid IN 
(SELECT viewer_id 
FROM views WHERE campaign_id 
    IN (@cid:=(SELECT * FROM(SELECT campaign_id FROM views 
    where campaign_id>'$firstCampaignId' AND campaign_id 
    IN (SELECT id FROM campaigns WHERE owner_yfid 
    IN (SELECT id FROM uc_users WHERE email='$email')) 
group by campaign_id having count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1) AS tmp))) 
AND gender = 1 AND age < 35
```

EDIT:
Ive found out that in MySQL workbench @cid is also NULL when Im running the query for the first time. When Im executing it for the second time, its returned correctly. So probably there is some problem with assigning logic? That is being assigned after excution of query and is accessible on second run?

Comment: Note: Be aware of security flaws like SQL-injection.

Comment: @MarcodeAbreu sure, dont worry Im aware of it. But thats not the scope of this question...

Comment: show your php code. what do you expect to get when `@cid:=(SELECT * `

Comment: Also be aware that the order of operations when updating an `@variable` inside of a MySQL query is intentionally left undefined, so you may get some intermittent unexpected behavior, or it may break without notice after even minor version upgrades. This is most likely not your issue, but something to be aware of.

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are doing? As far as I see you can select `campaign_id` instead of `@cid`. And you probably should use JOINs instead of nested WHERE IN subqueries.

Comment: Using joins and group by would be much better. Also agree with the points made by CollinD. Your query will not reliably reference the correct value in the column list of the first select.

Comment: @Alex Im expecting to store result of that subquery in variable, because i need to know to which id is the count(*) being associated.

Comment: Try aliasing it like `@cid AS cid`.

Comment: @inarilo Ive already tried it with no success

Comment: What is your php code?

Comment: @inarilo its only simple mysqli_query...

Comment: In view of your edit, my guess is `@cid` is not being selected the first time because it is assigned in a WHERE clause, by the second time it has already got a value which is then being selected because it's valid for the entire session.

Comment: @inarilo is there some way how to make it accessible "globally" ?

Comment: The query needs to be rewritten but it's very complicated! I'm trying to dissect it.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the query?

Comment: could you just provide raw data  and expected result? you can start with something like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af9979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
select count(*), @cid:=V.campaign_id from
( select yfid from users
  where gender = 1 AND age < 35
) as U
inner join
( select viewer_id, campaign_id FROM views 
  where campaign_id > '$firstCampaignId'
) as V on U.yfid = V.viewer_id
inner join
campaigns as C on V.campaign_id = C.id
inner join
( select id from uc_users where email='$email' ) as UCU on C.owner_yfid = UCU.id
group by V.campaign_id
having count(*) > 1 
order by count(*) desc limit 1
```

I prefer putting `where` clauses in subqueries to reduce the number of rows actually joined, though I did not find any information on whether MySQL optimises this already.

It does appear that MySQL optimises `join` statements but not `in` clauses.

Comment: It works, thanks ;) So to sum it up - the main problem was that I was assigning value to variable in subquery and that was the reason why it was not accessible as result of first execution of query in specific session. In PHP there was created new session every time I was calling the query so there was no chance to access value from variable, however in MySQL workbench the session stays open so the variable was accessible on the second run of query. So the solution was to pull the assigning of value to variable on top of all queries.

Comment: Yes, I think so, but I have not played around with session variables much so other ways may exist.